# Media module: how to generate a pdf link?

Tags: wysiwyg, media, files

I'm trying to use the media module to generate a link to a pdf that I uploaded using media module. The problem is that when I insert the pdf that is on my library and select the link format, it displays a missing image and does not generte my link. What should I do to make it generate the link to my pdf?

Comment: Which version of the file_entity module (https://drupal.org/project/file_entity) you use? The one compatible with the media module or the other?

Comment: Might be related - take a look at the pdf module (https://drupal.org/project/pdf) which uses HTML5 to generte PDF previews if users don't have pdf a plugin for their browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Check out your file-types display settings in `admin/config/media/file-types` in combination with the field display settings you are using.